# PayPal Future Payments with no Server

Tags: android, paypal

I have a requirement to enable two users on separate Android devices to agree a schedule of payments.  The schedule is agreed via Bluetooth and then the intention is for the Buyer to authorise it via the PayPal API and the seller to request the payments at the agreed intervals.

I've got up to the point of obtaining an Access and Refresh token, but then the documentation assumes the remaining PP transactions are done via the sellers server.

There is currently no intention for the seller to have this functionality on their server.  Is it possible, for instance using the REST API to take the payments from within the Sellers App?

I can't see any guidance for this approach in: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

Thanks for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, this use case is insecure and unsupported.  I suggest you implement the server yourself as a secure mechanism for making the future payments.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jeff - would you mind outlining why the approach is insecure compared to the server implementation.

Many Thanks Andy

Comment: To get the refresh_token and make payments, the client_secret is required.  This should never be stored on a device, lest it fall into malicious hands and be used to make payments to the malicious party.